# Format a date with MomentJS, without local time adjustment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to display a unix timestamp (which is in UTC) as a formatted date.

I also want to keep it in the UTC timezone (so no change to the hours based on TZ). How can I do this?

**Example:**

`moment(unix_timestamp).format('MMMM D, YYYY - H:mm:SS.SSSS')` converts the output into the computer's local time.

**Moment Docs:**

Found this section in the docs, but none of the options seem to work:
https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/local-utc-zone/

Comment: Did you try manipulating as UTC? As in `moment(unix_timestamp).utc().format('MMMM D, YYYY - H:mm:SS.SSSS')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as documentation states:

Note that if you use moment() or moment.utc() to parse a date with a specified offset, the date will be converted from that offset to either local or UTC:

```
moment('2016-01-01T00:00:00+02:00').format() //converted to local

moment.utc('2016-01-01T00:00:00+02:00').format() //treated as UTC
```

Comment: what's the meaning of "treated as UTC" ? will the `+02:00` used or not?